# Power Automate Desktop Selenium to VBA

Tags: selenium, power-automate-desktop

I have installed Power Automate Desktop. Is possible to link Selenium from Power Automate Desktop to VBA references?

Answer (score 0):

Power Automate Desktop has a recorder for web processes, if you need to call VBA, power automate has its section, if that doesn't work you can implement a console and run the script.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger your selenium script you can use

1. cmd/ command prompt (open CMD session) and give the proper path of your selenium project directory in power automate desktop
2. use "Write to cmd session" in power automate desktop and pass "mvn install" command.
   Make sure Maven is installed.

TO run VBA code you can

1. open the Excel instance
2. Run Excel macro
3. give the macro name